# Categorising data within a range in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data frame in R that has a personal ID, an income and some other variables. I would like to add a new column to this data that categorises people in to which income group they fit in to (0-24,999, 25,000-49,999, 50,000-74,999, 75000-99,000, etc).

I then want to be able to make frequency tables of this data compared with some of the other variables (eg: weekly hours worked, age).

I should be fine to figure out the latter of these problems, but I am having trouble figuring out how to categorise my data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you akrun. How do I name these categories? (eg: low, medium, high?)

Comment: Thank you I now know how to name the categories.

Comment: When I try and merge this with my original data set, it duplicated the rows a couple of times, so I have three times as many rows. Any idea what may have caused this?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cut` or `findInterval` to group the "Variable"

```
gr <- cut(df1$Variable, breaks = c(0, 24999, 49999,74999,99999, Inf))
```

Then, use `table` to get the frequency count

```
table(gr, df1$age)
```